# Python command repeats same number in command(im learning python)

Tags: python, random, numbers

I tried to make a twitter bot to print random number but it print the same number while testing the command

```
import tweepy
import random
import time
import threading
import schedule



start = time.perf_counter()
while time.perf_counter() - start < 2:
    random_number = random.randint(0,10000)
    time.sleep(1.0)



def job():  
    print(random_number)  

# run the function job() every 2 seconds  
schedule.every(2).seconds.do(job)  

while True:  
    schedule.run_pending()
```

What should I do in order to have random numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Your first block defines the `random_number`, which is then fixed.

You should compute the random number in your `job`

```
import random
import time
import threading
import schedule


def job():  
    print(random.randint(0,10000))  

# run the function job() every 2 seconds  
schedule.every(2).seconds.do(job)  

while True:  
    schedule.run_pending()
```